# How do I animate the rotation of a set of vectors in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vector, graphics, matlab-figure

I am trying to visualize the rotation of a coordinate system from a fixed world frame to a rotated body frame. I rotated the frame using a DCM and now I am trying to animate the movement of the new frame (which is 3 orthogonal vectors) from the initial frame to its rotated orientation.

I want to use quiver3 but I cannot get the previous quiver to delete itself from the plot before the next one is drawn. The result is a procession of arrows slowly changing size and turning until they reach their final orientation.

I suspect it is an issue with hold on/ hold off though I do not know.

If anyone could help me create a smooth animation of the vectors rotating in space from their initial starting position to their final orientation I would be appreciative.

Thanks!

```
clear all;
k = [0; 0; 1;];
j = [0; 1; 0;];
i = [1; 0; 0;];
starts = zeros(3,3);
ends = [i j k];
t = linspace(0,1,100);
yaw = pi/4;
pitch = pi/4;
roll = pi/4;
quiver3(starts(1,:), starts(2,:), starts(3,:), ends(1,:), ends(2,:), ends(3,:))
hold on;
for k = 1:length(t)
    hold on;
    yawDCM = [cos(yaw*t(k)) sin(yaw*t(k)) 0; -sin(yaw*t(k)) cos(yaw*t(k)) 0; 0 0 1*t(k)];
    pitchDCM = [cos(pitch*t(k)) 0 -sin(pitch*t(k)); 0 1*t(k) 0; sin(pitch*t(k)) 0 cos(pitch*t(k));];
    rollDCM = [1*t(k) 0 0; 0 cos(roll*t(k)) sin(roll*t(k)); 0 -sin(roll*t(k)) cos(roll*t(k));];
    Q = yawDCM*pitchDCM*rollDCM;
    ends2 = Q*ends;
%     hold on;
%     plot3(ends2(1,1), ends2(1,2), ends2(1,3), '--');
%     plot3(ends2(2,1), ends2(2,2), ends2(2,3), '--');
%     plot3(ends2(3,1), ends2(3,2), ends2(3,3), '--');
%     pause(.01);
%     hold off;
    quiver3(starts(:,1), starts(:,2), starts(:,3), ends2(:,1), ends2(:,2), ends2(:,3), 0);
    pause(.1);
    hold off
end
axis equal
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't have to use the hold on/off command. Just define the axes and your view so you can watch the rotation in a comfortable way. I used your code, actually you don't need the initialisation quiver but can directly start with the loop:

```
figure(1)
xlim([-0.5 1]); ylim([-0.5 1]); zlim([-0.5 1]);
view([45 45 45])
quiver3(starts(1,:), starts(2,:), starts(3,:), ends(1,:), ends(2,:), ends(3,:))
for k = 1:length(t)
    yawDCM = [cos(yaw*t(k)) sin(yaw*t(k)) 0; -sin(yaw*t(k)) cos(yaw*t(k)) 0; 0 0 1*t(k)];
    pitchDCM = [cos(pitch*t(k)) 0 -sin(pitch*t(k)); 0 1*t(k) 0; sin(pitch*t(k)) 0 cos(pitch*t(k));];
    rollDCM = [1*t(k) 0 0; 0 cos(roll*t(k)) sin(roll*t(k)); 0 -sin(roll*t(k)) cos(roll*t(k));];
    Q = yawDCM*pitchDCM*rollDCM;
    ends2 = Q*ends;
    quiver3(starts(:,1), starts(:,2), starts(:,3), ends2(:,1), ends2(:,2), ends2(:,3), 0);
    xlim([-0.5 1]); ylim([-0.5 1]); zlim([-0.5 1]);
    view([45 45 45])
    pause(.1);    
end
```

Answer (score 2):

**One approach** is to *remove all uses of `hold`* in your code. The `hold` state is `off` by default, so `quiver` *deletes the old plot and creates a new one in each iteration*. This has the unwanted effect that the scale of the axes will change to accomodate the changing arrow lengths (note that although `axis manual` may be used to freeze the axis scales, that only works when the `hold` state is `on`). To solve it you can *manually set axis sizes in each iteration*, after `quiver`. This is the approach used in [@Till's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66069441/2586922) (which I only just saw...).

A **second approach**, which I think is slightly better, is the following. You create the quiver plot initially, and within the loop instead of creating a new quiver plot *you simply change the data of the existing one*. These data are accessed via the [properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.quiver-properties.html) of the `quiver` object.

The advantages of the second approach are that you can set axis size once at the beginning, instead of in each iteration; and you avoid deleting the quiver plot and creating a new one every time. So the code will probably be *faster*, and will look *cleaner*:

```
clear
k = [0; 0; 1;];
j = [0; 1; 0;];
i = [1; 0; 0;];
starts = zeros(3,3);
ends = [i j k];
t = linspace(0,1,100);
yaw = pi/4;
pitch = pi/4;
roll = pi/4;
h = quiver3(starts(1,:), starts(2,:), starts(3,:), ends(1,:), ends(2,:), ends(3,:)); % create quiver object
axis([-.5 .8 -.5 1 0 1]); % choose axis size
view([-40 25]) % choose viewing angle
axis manual % this freezes axis size
for k = 1:length(t)
    yawDCM = [cos(yaw*t(k)) sin(yaw*t(k)) 0; -sin(yaw*t(k)) cos(yaw*t(k)) 0; 0 0 1*t(k)];
    pitchDCM = [cos(pitch*t(k)) 0 -sin(pitch*t(k)); 0 1*t(k) 0; sin(pitch*t(k)) 0 cos(pitch*t(k));];
    rollDCM = [1*t(k) 0 0; 0 cos(roll*t(k)) sin(roll*t(k)); 0 -sin(roll*t(k)) cos(roll*t(k));];
    Q = yawDCM*pitchDCM*rollDCM;
    ends2 = Q*ends;
    h.XData = starts(:,1); h.YData = starts(:,2); h.ZData = starts(:,2); % update quiver properties
    h.UData = ends2(:,1); h.VData = ends2(:,2); h.WData = ends2(:,3); % update quiver properties
    pause(.02);
end
```

Comment: Yeah, your second approach is definitely  better and more elegant than mine especially if `t` is becoming very high. Thanks :)